# Finding the solution of an linear differential equation with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following ODE
$$(D^3 + 8 )y = x^4 + 2x +1,$$ where $D=\frac{d}{dx}$

I found the complementary solution as $$C_1 e^{-2x} + e^x [C_2 \cos(\sqrt{3} x) + C_3 \sin(\sqrt{3} x)]$$

I used $D^3 + 8 = (D+2)(D^2 -2D+4). $

For finding particular solution I don't know how to solve. Please help me.

Comment: Try $y_p(x) = a_4*x^4 +...a_1*x + a_0$

Comment: I assume you that the square-roots only cover the $3$'s, and not the $x$'s?

Comment: yes, it covers only 3's